# sum two columns in R

Tags: r

I feel a bit embarrassed as I am trying to add two columns in R to get the product.

I have tried

```
sum(col1,col2)
```

but this returns

```
Error in Summary.factor(c(49L, 48L, 47L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 44L, 43L,  : 
  sum not meaningful for factors
```

I thought this would very simple! both columns contain integers.

Comment: Please include the result of `dput(head(yourdata))` in your question.

Comment: The error message seems rather informative. If you don't know what a factor is in R, then you need to go back to your introductory text and do some more self study.

Comment: "I am trying to add two columns in R to get the product" - Huh?

Comment: `with(mtcars, sum(factor(mpg), factor(cyl)))` versus `with(mtcars, sum(mpg, cyl))` should help you out a little

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `sum` function will add all numbers together to produce a single number, not a vector (well, at least not a vector of length greater than 1).

It looks as though at least one of your columns is a factor. You could convert them into numeric vectors by checking this

```
head(as.numeric(data$col1))  # make sure this gives you the right output
```

And if that looks right, do

```
data$col1 <- as.numeric(data$col1)
data$col2 <- as.numeric(data$col2)
```

You might have to convert them into characters first. In which case do

```
data$col1 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$col1))
data$col2 <- as.numeric(as.character(data$col2))
```

It's hard to tell which you should do without being able to see your data.

Once the columns are numeric, you just have to do

```
data$col3 <- data$col1 + data$col2
```

Comment: How would you deal with NAs in one of those columns? Do you need to replace them with 0 before the addition or can you do this in one go?

Comment: It depends on how you want to handle NAs. If you want them to be zero, you'll need to do that at any point before you do the addition.

Answer (score 4):

```
tablename$column3=rowSums(cbind(tablename$column1,tablename$column2),na.rm=TRUE)
```

This can be used to ignore blank values in the excel sheet.
I have used for Euro stat dataset.

This example works in R:

```
crime_stat_data$All_theft <-rowSums(cbind(crime_stat_data$Theft,crime_stat_data$Theft_of_a_motorised_land_vehicle, crime_stat_data$Burglary, crime_stat_data$Burglary_of_private_residential_premises), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: this solution addresses NA values - important

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   df$col3[i] <- df$col1[i] + df$col2[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## First way

```
df$New1 <- df$X1+df$X2+df$X3
```

## Second Way

```
df <-df %>% select(contains('X')) %>% mutate(New2=rowSums(.))
```

Comment: For a better reading experience, it would be better if you add the code inside a code brackets. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that one or two of your columns may have a factor in them, or what is more likely is that your columns may be formatted as factors.  Please would you give str(col1) and str(col2) a try?  That should tell you what format those columns are in.

I am unsure if you're trying to add the rows of a column to produce a new column or simply all of the numbers in both columns to get a single number.

Comment: hi reuben I want add cell 1 of column 1 to cell 1 of column 2 etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
    df <- data.frame("a" = c(1,2,3,4), "b" = c(4,3,2,1), "x_ind" = c(1,0,1,1), "y_ind" = c(0,0,1,1), "z_ind" = c(0,1,1,1) )
df %>% mutate( bi  = ifelse((df$x_ind + df$y_ind +df$z_ind)== 3, 1,0 ))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this for creating a column3 as a sum of column1 + column 2 in a table

```
tablename$column3=rowSums(cbind(tablename$column1,tablename$column2))
```