# R dplyr mutate on column index

Tags: r, dplyr

Building on this question: [dplyr: how to reference columns by column index rather than column name using mutate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618744/dplyr-how-to-reference-columns-by-column-index-rather-than-column-name-using-mu)

I want to mutate using column indexes for both the source and the destination of the mutate:

```
iris %>% head %>% mutate(.[[1]] = .[[1]] + .[[2]])
```

gives:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "iris %>% head %>% mutate(.[[1]] =".
```

However, the following works:

```
iris %>% head %>% mutate(sum = .[[1]] + .[[2]])
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in ways that are not supported.  There is already standard ways to call the column with column names.  If there are columns that start with number, change it to standard names as it will become difficult while you do this on other cases

Comment: I'm making a generic function to work on multiple tables with different column names, but the same data format. I could temporaily rename the columns make the mutate and give them back their old names, but this would be a neater solution. If this isn't supported, then that's the answer I was looking for

Comment: In that case, it would be better to use `base R` `iris[[1]] <- iris[[1]] + iris[[2]]`

Comment: Thanks, that solves it, I'm always confused why these questions get voted down though, there are often other ways at solving things in R. Was this a silly question? Should I remove it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum two columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046776/sum-two-columns-in-r)

Comment: I don't think so, this is about dplyr and using a column index for the destination and source.

Comment: Have you found a `dplyr` solution to this problem

Comment: Afraid not, would be interested if someone else has though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in `base R`

```
iris[[1]] <- iris[[1]] + iris[[2]]
```

Comment: Can this be used to select, for example the second to last column? 

`iris %>% head %>% mutate(sum = .[[1]] + .[[-2]])` does not work

Comment: @PhillipBlack Did you meant `iris %>% head  %>% mutate(sum = rowSums(.[2:(ncol(.)-1)]))`

Comment: exactly! for on lookers: .[[(ncol(.)-1)]] and  [(ncol(.)-1)] will call either a vector of the column or the column itself.

Comment: @akrun, I'm with the same issue `aeps_1_fine %>% 
    mutate(.[[1]] = as.numeric(.[[1]]))` . Any way to do this one with mutate?

Comment: @Luis you can use `aeps_1_fine %>% mutate(!! names(.)[1] := as.numeric(!! rlang::sym(names(.)[1])))` or use across i.e. `aeps_1_fine %>% mutate(across(1, as.numeric))`

Comment: I don't know how you know so much about R and R programming!! Thanks much! It worked!