# join and sum columns together R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ca = c("a","b","a","c","b", "b"),
                 f = c(3,4,0,NA,3, 4),
                 f2 = c(NA,5,6,1,9, 7),
                 f3 = c(3,0,6,3,0, 8))
```

I want join and sum my columns "f" and "f2" and rename it in "f_news"

exemple :

```
df <- data.frame(ca = c("a","b","a","c","b", "b"),
                 f_new = c(3,9,6,1,12, 11),
             
                 f3 = c(3,0,6,3,0, 8))
```

Do you have an idea of how to do this with summarise, spread, group_by?

Comment: What do you mean by join ? When you sum and one of the terms is NA, the sum is NA.

Comment: Hi, it's possible that I didn't express myself well. I'm going to sum up this two columns and create another column that would have the information of this sum, to have the result as in the example. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sum two columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046776/sum-two-columns-in-r)

Comment: Try `rowSums(df[, c("f", "f2")], na.rm = TRUE)` which will be really fast and doesn't require any extra packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `plyr` and `dplyr` you can do this:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(f_new=sum(f, f2, na.rm = T))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
#   ca     f    f2    f3   f_new
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   a     3    NA     3     3
#2   b     4     5     0     9
#3   a     0     6     6     6
#4   c    NA     1     3     1
#5   b     3     9     0    12
#6   b     4     7     8    11
```

This method will retain and `NA` values

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer using `tidyverse` methods from `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ca = c("a","b","a","c","b", "b"),
                 f = c(3,4,0,NA,3, 4),
                 f2 = c(NA,5,6,1,9, 7),
                 f3 = c(3,0,6,3,0, 8))

df %>% 
  replace_na(list(f = 0, f2 = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(f_new = f + f2)
#>   ca f f2 f3 f_new
#> 1  a 3  0  3     3
#> 2  b 4  5  0     9
#> 3  a 0  6  6     6
#> 4  c 0  1  3     1
#> 5  b 3  9  0    12
#> 6  b 4  7  8    11
```

Answer (score 2):

Dplyr can do this quite nice with the following code. Rowwise allows you to consider each row separately. And the mutate command sums whatever columns you want. the na.rm=TRUE handles the issue when you have NA's and want to ignore them. As a comment mentioned, if you do not have this, it will give you an NA if it's in any of the summed values.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(f_new = sum(f,f2, na.rm = TRUE))
```